# How do I install gscam in groovy?

Tags: ros-groovy, gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I install gscam in groovy and how do I find out in which deb a package is or find out that the deb does not exist anymore?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57319/how-do-i-install-gscam-in-groovy?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`gscam` has sort of been abandoned. There are several forks in the wild:

- https://github.com/jhu-lcsr-forks/gscam (forked from experimental svn [here](http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/gscam/) which currently looks broken)
- https://github.com/BeLioN-github/gscam
- https://github.com/RLAB/gscam
- https://github.com/uml-robotics/brown_perception

I really think these should be unified, since there are a lot of bugfixes in these non-trunk versions that have not been merged. I'm about to start using it again, too.

UPDATE: I've updated the [JHU-LCSR fork](https://github.com/jhu-lcsr-forks/gscam) to be a buildable in a catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-06**:
If you want to maintain a merged version, it could go in https://github.com/organizations/ros-drivers

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-06**:
I might do just that...

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-08**:
I've updated my fork (https://github.com/jhu-lcsr-forks/gscam) and e-mailed the original authors to get their OK for moving it over to ros-drivers.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see any Ubuntu binary packages for it in the repository, so you'll probably need to download the source and build it. According to the [wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gscam), the SVN source is here:

- https://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distribution/brown_perception.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-03-06**:
OK. I had done it before downloading the source and catkinized it. But now I wanted to tell other people how to install the package and thougt it should be easier to do. Is there a command to automatically download and build it?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-06**:
You should not need to catkinize it. Just use rosws to build a source overlay, and rosmake to build it.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-03-06**:
Yes, I know. But since the compile time for rosbuild was very slow in groovy when I did it I converted it since I needed anyway to do some local modifications. I have started to like catkin and want to only use that...